# Updated ThreeJS and now instanceof doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I updated to r99 and now I'm finding that any instanceof checking I'm doing no longer works.

For instance when I traverse this object and check if children are Mesh, it's returning as false. However, if I take a look at `child.constructor.name` it is reporting as Mesh.

```
object.traverse(child => {
    console.log(child);
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        console.log('THREE.Mesh');
    } else {
        console.log('NOT THREE.Mesh');
    }
    console.log(child.constructor.name);
    console.log('----');
}
```

[image]

What could have possibly went wrong/changed when I simply updated the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure how the `object` you're traversing was created without being able to see that code, but it's possible that the loader you're using changed its methodology.

When checking types, I recommend you use the built-in `.type` property, which is also what Three.js internally uses to differentiate what type of objects it's dealing with. The problem with using `instanceof` is that you could get ambiguous results when dealing with subclasses:

```
var myMesh = new THREE.Mesh();
console.log(myMesh instanceof THREE.Mesh);      // True
console.log(myMesh instanceof THREE.Object3D);  // Also true
```

However, if you check for the `.type` property, you'll get more certainty on what you're dealing with.

```
console.log(myMesh.type === "Mesh");        // True
console.log(myMesh.type === "Object3D");    // False
```